# Codeigniter 1and1 email

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I am having trouble with accessing 1and1 email via SMTP, on their website they state that following information should be used for the SMTP

```
Outgoing (SMTP) Server  smtp.1and1.com
Outgoing port with TLS enabled  587
Outgoing server requires authentication?    Yes
```

But, when I use it in email config file within codeigniter I get no results from following config:

```
$config['protocol'] = "smtp";
$config['smtp_host'] = "smtp.1and1.com";
$config['smtp_port'] = "587";
$config['smtp_user'] = "noreply@domain.com";
$config['smtp_pass'] = "noreply";
$config['smtp_crypto'] = 'tls';


$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

$config['crlf'] = '\r\n';   
$config['newline'] = '\r\n';
```

Also, the email debug function returns:

```
The following SMTP error was encountered: 
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.
```

Comment: there seem to be an issue with codeigniter, the TLS side of things required more work, i have ended up using https://github.com/ivantcholakov/codeigniter-phpmailer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there seem to be an issue with codeigniter, the TLS side of things required more work, i have ended up using github.com/ivantcholakov/codeigniter-phpmailer

This library is easy to install and quick to run.

Answer (score 2):

```
$config1and1 = array(
            'protocol' => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'smtp.1and1.es',
            'smtp_port' => 587,
            'smtp_crypto' => 'tls',
            'smtp_user' => 'your full email', //example: jujo@domain.com
            'smtp_pass' => 'mail pass',
            'mailtype' => 'html',
            'charset' => 'utf-8',
            'newline' => "\r\n"
        );
```

if you don't want mail type html can choice another type. i hope that help it ;)

Comment: had to set all parameters listed up here.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the line

```
$config['newline'] = '\r\n';
$config['crlf'] = '\r\n';
```

'\r\n' should be written in double quotes.

So the line should be

```
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";
 $config['crlf'] = "\r\n";
```

Hope this works.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this?

```
$config['smtp_port'] = 587;
```

Without quotes.

With qoutes you pass a string, without quotes an integer

Comment: sadly quotes didn't make much of a difference.